# Constraint equality of parameters in MATLAB fmincon

Tags: maximum-likelihood, matlab, likelihood, constraint

I am estimating a Vector Autoregression where the independent variables are all interacted by a dummy variable and represents economic regimes.
The VAR looks like this:
$$Y_t=\mu+\Phi Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$ where $\epsilon \tilde (0,\Sigma)$

I estimate the VAR by Maximum Likelihood and have in the set of the parameters $Nreg*Ny*Nx+Nreg*Nx*Nx$ parameters where Nreg is the number of regimes (here, 2), Ny is the number of dependent variables (here, 7) and Nx is the number of independent variables. The first term is thus the number of regression coefficients and the second is the number of variance-covariance matrix elements.

I want to estimate the whole set of parameters given that the variance-covariance matrices are identical.

For this, I am using MATLAB fmincon.

In the documentation, I read that I have to use the Aeq and beq matrices such that $Aeq*x=beq$.

Since I want some of my parameters to be equal to each other, I have to set up the constraint such that the sum of 1 parameter and the opposite of the corresponding parameter in the other regime is zero. For example, $\Sigma_1(1,1)=\Sigma_2(1,1)$ or $\Sigma_1(1,1)-\Sigma_2(1,1)=0$, which works fine for two regimes but breaks down if I have more than 2. I doubt that I have to add every combination of the constraint two by two in order to obtain a constraint that would look like this: $\Sigma_1(1,1)=\Sigma_2(1,1)=\Sigma_3(1,1)$

The alternative is to penalize the Likelihood value if the matching parameters are not identical:

```
if sigma_1(1,1)~=sigma_2(1,1)
llk=10^12;
end
```

What would be the best strategy?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Say you would like to include $A=B=C$ into matlab, then you should include two constaints; namely $A=B$ and $B=C$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's what I thought, but as the number of regimes _and_ elements to be constrained increase, the number of constraints increase dramatically. Maybe it renders the estimation very difficult ?